# Redirect one public IP to another public IP, different subnets and servers

Tags: linux, iptables, routing

That's my first question here so I hope I'll structure it right.

Since it is a case for a friend, I'll appreciate guideness for a proper setup because I won't be able to access the environment.

In short - there is Server A with one public ip (31.x.x.x) on eth0. It was running a service on speciffic port, listening for udp connections. The public service has been moved to Server B which has again eth0 with again public ip, but on entirely different subnet. (93.x.x.x).

The goal is to redirect all connections coming to the old ip on server A to the new ip on server b. Server B needs to know the original source ip of the packet.

We've tried some configs with iptables on Server A, using dnat for prerouting and snat/masquerade for postrouting and it works, but the service on Server B sees the packets as they are comming from the public ip on server A.

I've read that the postrouting should be removed and server b should use server a as default gw when returning such packets, but I don't think it is possible, because they are on entirely different networks.

Any help how can we acheive the goal is appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This is what DNS is for.

Comment: The service is accessed via IP and port. Clients are not using domain name. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: They _should_ be using a DNS name to access the service.

Comment: I know but it's a bit more complicated. The interface of the software that uses the service allows you to add this service via domain name. However after successful resolution of the domain name, it stores the IP and port of the service and connects to them. Since the service is moved, the domain name points to the new IP and port, but a lot of people still use the previously added via the same domain name IP and port.

Comment: You're screwed.  There's no way you can do what you want to do.

Comment: That software is broken, then. It's not supposed to be "storing" the IP address in that manner. Not much you can do unless you can fix it.

Comment: Let's say those two public IP addresses are part of two subnets consisting of exactly 16 IP addresses and that we can route them both through two separate /30 networks provided by the ISPs. Is this acheivable? Or if we add one more interface on the Server B with IP from the subnet of server A? Or something like this. Any workaround possible without rewriting the software is welcomed.

Comment: Your best workaround at this point is to physically move server B to the same location as server A, so that you can give it server A's IP address. And then rewrite your software to use DNS properly.

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that there is already a second service just like this running on server A with the same IP but different port. It's already too much for server A so he moved it to server B. And as you can guess - we can't move the other service for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

### Potential solution 1

What I would try to do (it should work but I have not tested it):

1. Get a second IP available on the new server. Configure it using another network namespace (you can use something like Docker for it).
2. Create a tunnel (using GRE is probably the easiest but you can do anything, including IPSEC, OpenVPN, etc.) between the 2 serves.
3. For the new network namespace that you have created, use the tunnel as default route.
4. Setup TPROXY on the source / old machine and NAT to the second IP.

Now, everything is a bit tricky because it is also UDP. You will need to mess a lot with connection tracking.

### Possible solution 2

Another thing you can do, way easier: write a custom tunneling app, taking advantage that this UDP. It should do something like this:

1. The source part of the app would listen on UDP on the old server.
2. The dest part of the app would listen on TCP on the new server.
3. The source part of the app sends each UDP packet, including the IP headers via the TCP connection it has towards the dest server.
4. The dest part of the app, while it receives data on the TCP stream, rebuilds the UDP packet, including the IP headers, and sends it to the UDP port on localhost. IP spoofing should work just fine on localhost.

Of course, this would cause some latency on the UDP packets but it would do the job.